Google Sheets Vlookup doesn't search for the exact value
I'm currently developing a Google Sheet.
Currently it has multiple tabs, all data is stored in tab 'Antwoorden'. And I want to get summary in tab 'Etiket'.
On tab 'Etiket' I've create a data validation which is gathering his data from 'Antwoorden!$BZ:$BZ' (see screenshot)
After I select the correct name in this drop down the value on A3 needs to be adjusted by the number of Antwoorden!CA

Note: Data in column CA is gathered via =B2&" "&C2
I've tried multiple things like Vlookup and Query but I'm unable to gather the correct number:
=LOOKUP(B3,Antwoorden!CB:CB,Antwoorden!CA:CA)
I hope that someone can help me!
Thanks!

It would help if you made this spreadsheet (or an anonymised copy) available for people to view.

Vlookup() probably has an optional argument to control the type of search: true or 1 for nearest and False or 0 for exact. So check the function you use.

Although I think you just need to put "FALSE" as a 4th argument in the VLOOKUP https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en-GB

@SamDean most of us do not open shared files just in case of a virus or malware... A decent clear example, with the function shown as text is usually more than ample...


As per LOOKUP() documentation:
LOOKUP(search_key, search_range|search_result_array, [result_range])


The LOOKUP function will only work properly if data in search_range or search_result_array is sorted. Use VLOOKUP, HLOOKUP, or other
related functions if data is not sorted.

You may try this for your test dataset:
=xlookup(B3,Antwoorden!CB:CB,Antwoorden!CA:CA,"No_Match_found")

